# How to load the latest record on top Django New User

Tags: python, django

I am trying to load the latest record on top based on the time and date added. I have already assigned the following values in MODELS.PY

```
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I also try to add this in my view function but it didn't work

def client_list(request):

```
context = {'client_list':Client.objects.all()}
ordering = ['-date_posted']
return render(request, 'client_register/client_list.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you show us models, is date_posted in Client model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're defining the ordering, but never aplying it to context since generic functions view don't have `ordering` attribute. Maybe you were treating it as a ListView, which it is not (for ListView docs, please check [CCVB ListView](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.list/ListView/)).

Going back to your question... Replace context with this:

```
context = {'client_list':Client.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted')}
```

That should work.

Also I would recomend you not to use `date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)`, try using:

```
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

That is going to save the date the instance is created.